# How to take only one value from an array in a document using 'distinct' mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following collection :

```
[
    {
        'item' : 'A',
        'colors' : [
               'a1', 'a2', 'a3'
        ]
    },
    {
        'item' : 'B',
        'colors' : [
               'b1', 'b2', 'b3'
        ]
    },
    {
        'item' : 'A',
        'colors' : [
               'c1', 'c2', 'c3'
        ]
    },
    {
        'item' : 'A',
        'colors' : [
               'd1', 'd2', 'd3'
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get the distinct colors of all items with `'item': 'A'`. But, here is the catch. I want only the first color in the array of a document having `'item': 'A'`. The output should look something like:

```
[ 
     'a1',
     'c1',
     'd1',
]
```

I used to 'distinct' keyword as follows

```
db.collection.distinct('colors',{'item' : 'A'})
```

but this gives me

```
[ 
     'a1',
     'a2',
     'a3',
     'c1',
     'c2',
     'c3',
     'd1',
     'd2',
     'd3'
]
```

How can I get the desired output?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the positional index parameter and filter query to distinct method.

```
db.collection.distinct("colors.0" ,{"item":'A'});
```

The following query will produce unique first elements for each item using aggregation pipeline stages [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/). If you want just for item A then enable match stage. Check the [results](https://mongoplayground.net/p/koyLFv-0r2y).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 //  {
 //  $match: {
 //   item: 'A'
 //    }
 // }, 
   {$project: {    
     item:1,
     firstColor:{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$colors", 0 ] }
    }}, {$group: {
      _id: "$item",
      uniqueFirstColorValues: {
        $addToSet : "$firstColor"
      }
    }}])
```